# How to solve simple ODE with FEM

Tags: finite-element-method

How to solve
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(x)=y(x)\\
y(0)=1
\end{cases}
$$
using finite element method?? I mean Bubnov-Galerkin approximation method along with Ritz minimization. I've try for some times and it looks like i don't understand something.

Comment: This is an initial value problem. In order to solve numerically using FEM methods, you need another boundary condition, like $y(A) = B$. Then the problem becomes a "boundary condition" problem, which is slightly different.

Comment: So the bottom line is: __don't__ solve time-stepping with FEM; use a finite difference scheme instead. Believe me: I've tried both.

Comment: To solve ivp you need a last basis function that is free. This gives a singular stiffness matrix if there is a 2nd order derivative, I have not yet tried for the case given. Note that for a variable coefficient linear ode like $y'(x)+a(x)y(x)=0$ there are two possibilities of discretization : $\sum a_ky_k\phi_k(x)$ or $\sum a_ky_l\phi_k(x)\phi_l(x)$. In the latter case there are terms like $a_{k+1}y_k$ appearing